# Play sd card videos using Jiecao Video Player?

Tags: android, video-player

I am using `Jiecao Video Player` to play streaming videos. I have to play `sdcard` videos also. I don't know how to do this. If anyone help me, It will be more useful. Thanks in advance. I used the following code. refer the link

https://github.com/lipangit/jiecaovideoplayer

```
JCVideoPlayerFullscreen jcVideoPlayerStandardShowTitleAfterFullscreen = (JCVideoPlayerFullscreen) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);
        jcVideoPlayerStandardShowTitleAfterFullscreen.setUp("http://video.jiecao.fm/5/1/%E8%87%AA%E5%8F%96%E5%85%B6%E8%BE%B1.mp4"
                , "嫂子摸完没");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but you can use this one.

```
int video_column_index = videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            videoCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String videoUri = videoCursor.getString(video_column_index);
 JCVideoPlayerFullscreen jcVideoPlayerStandardShowTitleAfterFullscreen = (JCVideoPlayerFullscreen) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);
        jcVideoPlayerStandardShowTitleAfterFullscreen.setUp(videoUri 
                , fileName);
```

Comment: How to auto start using this libary ??